# cwac locpoll demo crashes

Tags: commonsware-cwac

sorry for my bad english.

i'm trying to use your demo cwac locpoll, but always crashes for my, and then is dificult to see your jar work.

say me this:
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.demo.LocationPollerDemo.onCreate(LocationPollerDemo.java:42)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-14 01:47:19.880: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, it feels like your project is misconfigured. The `demo/` project needs to either:

- have a reference to the parent project as a library project, or
- have a copy of the `LocationPoller` JAR in its `libs/` directory

Your error feels like you did neither of these, but instead manually messed with the build path or something to get the `LocationPoller` classes in there, and usually such approaches only work at compile time.